# Merge files in different directories

Tags: files, csv

I have 3 dirs with csv files with the same name

```
/dir1/ex1.csv
/dir2/ex1.csv
/dir3/ex1.csv
```

And i would like to merge the content in just one destination file (Just concat file content, since is a csv without headers is ok)

```
/dir_final/ex1.csv
```

How could be a good way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what `cat` is for, to con**cat**enate files together. So just do:

```
cat /dir1/ex1.csv /dir2/ex1.csv /dir3/ex1.csv > /dir_final/ex1.csv
```